# Setting up a US-landline/Europe-landline voip connection

Tags: voip

I need to provide a clients in the US an ability to call a US landline phone, and have the call routed to the mobile phone in europe, where our office is located.

I need to have it implemented at a lowest cost possible.

Here is a system setup I have in mind:

1. Signup with a company that provides US landline-to-voip services.
2. Set up an asterisk server in a European office, and configure it up to recieve calls from a provider in step 1.
3. Set up an asterisk to make a call to a local mobile phone number with the help of the local landline connected to it.

My questions about this idea are the following:

1. Is there an asterisk-integrated landline/voip providers? Is this kind of service a common type?
2. Will asterisk be able to carry out tasks discribed in the model?
3. (Partially out of scope) Since I need initially to just have two numbers, maybe it will be less expensive to get the whole thing from an all-in-one provider like skype or some other?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic for SU, but i've used ipkall with a sip provider to do something similar to what you've done. It might be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max, you have **wrong** idea. You have to find SIP-operator, which give DID-numbers in +1 area in addition to ordinary SIP-account and method of redirecting incoming SIP-calls to PSTN-other networks

- [Continent Telecom](http://virtual-local-numbers.com/)
- [OnSIP](http://www.onsip.com/features/enterprise-phone-system)
- [Sipgate](http://www.sipgate.com/editions)
- [Telphin](http://telphin.ru/index.php/numbers/worldnumbers)
- [Zadarma](http://zadarma.com/en/intertel/dirnum/)

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way would be Skype Online Number - http://www.skype.com/intl/en/features/allfeatures/online-number/

Comment: Cheapest?! Don't be fooled